# Beautiful Soup, Ignoring Everything After A Comma

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm new to using python and beautiful soup. I am using bs4 and python 2.7. I have a problem with a string that I'm getting from bs4. Currently my code is returning Brooklyn NY, 12200. Is it possible to ignore everything after the ','?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split by the comma and get only the first part - the index 0 element.

```
>> text = "Brooklyn NY, 12200"
>> print text.split(',')[0]
Brooklyn NY
```

Also if you don't have `,` in you text, this code still works.

```
>> # No comma in this case
>> text = "Brooklyn NY 12200"
>> print text.split(',')[0]
Brooklyn NY 12200
```